# Minecraft black screen shader when not on menu

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, technical-issues, minecraft-shader

I have already used Minecraft shaders, the thing is that the shaders works only on menu when I press <kbd>esc</kbd>, but when I want to go back, normally, it turns black, anyone knows what might be the problem? I'm using 1.8.9 and the shader Sildurs vibrant shaders v1.28 Lite, the thing is I also thought it was the shader, and tried with other shaders and the same thing happens.

[image]

Comment: read [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)